# UITabBarController.moreNavigationController disable items

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am using UITabBarController for my 7 viewcontorller. UITabBarController is showing by default more button. When I pressed more button it will show me table view which contains 3 more tabbar items in list. I would like to disable one items from tableview list. Could you please help me how can I disable only single item from tableview list?

thanks
Manoj

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation for the [cusomizableViewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006931-CH3-SW11) property of UITabBarController. This property is an array that contains the subset of all your tab view controllers that are 'customizable' i.e. that can be moved around and added to the tab bar.

Remove a view controller from this array to disable customization.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable / enable items from the "More" tab bar item. You can remove one or many, as you want, though, by changing the array in the UITabBar's **items** property.